# how to add item collection to trackbar in winforms

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have a track bar in the form. I want to map the track bar value with collection of string. Like items in the combo-box.

I can do this with separate collection by using the track bars value as index to the collection.

Is there a better way to do this.

Comment: Can you share an image or describe more about the requirement?

Comment: Can you show your existing code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can customize yourself, like this:

```
public class MyTrackBar : TrackBar
    {
        public MyTrackBar()
        {
            InitItems(Maximum);
        }

        private void InitItems(int count)
        {
            Items = new List<string>(Maximum);
            for (int i = 0; i < Maximum; i++)
            {
                Items.Add("Item" + i); // or any text, or empty.
            }
        }

        public new int Maximum
        {
            get { return base.Maximum; }
            set
            {
                base.Maximum = value;
                InitItems(value);
            }
        }

        public List<string> Items { get; private set; }

        public string TextValue
        {
            get { return Items[Value]; }
        }

        public void ChangeText(int index, string text)
        {
            // ...
            Items[index] = text;
        }
    }
```